# Does a Minkowski functional satisfying absolutely homogeneity imply its associated set is balanced?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $p_K$ is a Minkowski functional induced by a convex and absorbing set $K$ in a complex vector space $X$. If $p_K$ satisfies
\begin{equation*}
p_K(ax)=|a|p_K(x) \quad (\forall x\in X, \forall a\in \mathbb{C}).
\end{equation*}
Then, is $K$ a balanced set?  Here, a balanced set $B$ is defined as follows:
\begin{equation*}
x\in B \Rightarrow ax\in B\quad (\forall |a|\leqslant 1).
\end{equation*}
If it is, how can we prove that? If not, can we construct a counterexample?

Any answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.

Let $K$ be any nonbalanced subset of $\mathbb C$ containing the open unit disc $D=\{z\in\mathbb C~|~|z|<1\}$ and contained in the closed unit disc $\overline D=\{z\in\mathbb C~|~|z|\leq 1\}$ (for example $K=D\cup\{1\}$).

Since $K$ contains $D$ and is contained in $\overline D$, you have $p_{\overline D}\leq p_K\leq p_D$. But $D$ and $\overline D$ have the same Minkowski functional: $p_D$ and $p_{\overline D}$ are equal to the absolute value $z\mapsto|z|$, which is of course absolutely homogeneous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!